# Healtcast HealthMonitor over rest

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast, health-monitoring

Is there any way we can have Hazel cast health monitor over rest end point. I can see hazelcast provides rest end point for health check but could not find any for [healthmonitor](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#health-monitor).

Basically i need below all health monitor values on rest.

> processors=2, physical.memory.total=47.0G,
>   physical.memory.free=476.7M, swap.space.total=2.0G,
>   swap.space.free=1.4G, heap.memory.used=435.9M, heap.memory.free=1.5G,
>   heap.memory.total=1.9G, heap.memory.max=1.9G,
>   heap.memory.used/total=22.55%, heap.memory.used/max=22.55%,
>   minor.gc.count=13, minor.gc.time=5598ms, major.gc.count=3,
>   major.gc.time=1439ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=0.00%,
>   load.systemAverage=0.99, thread.count=81, thread.peakCount=96,
>   cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0,
>   executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
>   executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
>   executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0,
>   executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=92223,
>   executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0,
>   executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
>   operations.running.count=0,
>   operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%,
>   operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=13,
>   clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=2,
>   client.connection.count=0, connection.count=2

Answer (score 0):

Nope, Hazelcast doesn't provide those metrics via REST. But feel free to make a feature request or contribution, here is the [Hazelcast GitHub repo](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a Jet job that reads these health monitor logs from server logs and stores in a Hazelcast map as value against timestamp as key. You can then access this map through REST.